# How can I make sparse image mounts not take space on my HD?

Tags: macos, mount

I have a sparse image on my external USB connected hard drive, and my space on the HD is running low. When I try mounting the sparse image on the external drive, I get a message saying that my startup disk is almost full. I would like it not to take up space if that is possible.

I have already tried to `hdiutil attach` it with the mount point being in my external drive's mount, but that just made the sparse image's mount invisible, and still taking up space.

Comment: Before the mount and after the mount - what are the counts for `df -h /` ? My guess is the OS is simply caching something to puging data to swap. You might also open a shell in terminal and rule out swapping by looking at the columns "pageins  pageout  swapins swapouts"

Comment: @bmike The values for my HD partition disk0s2 looks the same. But about yesterday, the mount took up space.

Comment: Chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27570522#27570522 – please incorporate the essence into the opening post here.